# Human Interface Guidelines - size of custom tab bar icons?

Tags: ios

I understand that I must provide icon sizes at 1x, 2x, and 3x for different screen resolutions:

> A standard resolution image has a scale factor of 1.0 and is referred
>   to as an @1x image. High resolution images have a scale factor of 2.0
>   or 3.0 and are referred to as @2x and @3x images. Suppose you have a
>   standard resolution @1x image that’s 100px × 100px, for example. The
>   @2x version of this image would be 200px × 200px. The @3x version
>   would be 300px × 300px.

What size should a custom tab bar icon be?  I can't seem to find it in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple Human Interface Guidelines:

Tab bar icon size:

Recommended
75px × 75px (25pt × 25pt @3x),
50px × 50px (25pt × 25pt @2x),
25px × 25px (25pt × 25pt @1x)

Maximum
144px × 96px (48pt × 32pt @3x),
96px × 64px (48pt × 32pt @2x),
48px × 32px (48pt × 32pt @1x)

You can check it on the link below :-
Link:- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/